# How to start netcat in listening mode from another host?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, bash, freebsd

I have a script where I would like to start `nc` in listening mode on `10.10.10.11`, but I would like to do it from `10.10.10.10`, where I have this script

```
ssh -n 10.10.10.11 nc -l 8023 | mbuffer -s 128k -m 1G | zfs receive $zfsPath
zfs send $newestSnap | mbuffer -s 128k -m 1G | nc -w 60 10.10.10.11 8023
```

The problem is, that if I execute the script from `10.10.10.10` then it won't continue after the first line have been executed, because `nc` is now waiting/listening for a connection on port 8023.

**Question**

I would like to execute the above from `10.10.10.10`, but how do I get it to continue after the first line?

Comment: You can start things in the background by using `&` behind the command. I am not sure of the precise syntax, but if you put all in one [shell]command and add & it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
ssh -n 10.10.10.11 "nc -l 8023 | mbuffer -s 128k -m 1G | zfs receive $zfsPath &"
zfs send $newestSnap | mbuffer -s 128k -m 1G | nc -w 60 10.10.10.11 8023
```

This runs the command and puts it in the background allowing control to pass on to the next line.

I don't have a zfs system to hand so  tested it with

```
ssh -n remote.tld  "nc -l 8023 | wc -l  >/tmp/test &"
ls | nc -w 60 remote.tld 8023
```

and the correct output appeared in the remote `/tmp/test` file.